# My 94 Toyota 4runner doesn't seem to gain speed even while I'm flooring the gas pedal...whats the issue and how can I fix it?

Tags: engine, toyota, 4runner

94 toy 4runner 6 cylinder. Just replaced sparkplug wires and distributor cap..

Comment: Does it rev when you throttle?

Comment: Also, did you have this issue before you changed the wires/cap?

Comment: Can you give us a more in depth description of whats going on? 
i.e "sounds, does it do it more sometimes rather than others, is it a manual or automatic". That would help us help you.

Comment: You need to give more details on the symptoms here, otherwise we could guess dozens of things.  How was it running before you did the change?